# cookie set is not working

Tags: java, ajax, apache, cookies

I'm trying to add a cookie for an ajax request to a backend server:

```
$.cookie("JSESSIONID", jsession);
```

problem is when the request is executed the cookie is not attached. any ideas why?

btw: both the projects are located on local vpn :

```
front end :  10.0.50.18

back end: 10.0.110.42
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so i found out what the problem is:

When you use cross domain ajax - a simple "POST" request is always preceded by an "OPTIONS" call first, this call was rejected by my security filter. the 2nd call ("POST") actually does use the cookie while the "OPTIONS" call not.